# ADO.NET Entity Framework In A COM Visible C# Class Library

Tags: c#, com, ado.net

I have a C# class library which I have made COM visible so I can also call it from legacy applications written in Visual Studio 6. This library has an Entity Framework in it for adding records to a database. Calling the library via COM works but the records do not get added to the database. I decided that the easiest way to debug this would be to add a C# WinForms test app to the library solution. This is where I noticed that the Entity Framework was failing here too. It turns out this is due to the app.config connection string in the library needing to be part of the test application too. That's fine and doing that means that the WinForms app works correctly and the records are added to the database.

However, how can I also fix this for calls via COM from legacy apps? Obviously they don't have an app.config.

Comment: hard code the connection string into an adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just putting app.config near your COM exe-file?
If that won't work, then your library cannot use default connection string from app.config. Instead it should:

1. Read it from registry or configuration file manually (maybe ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration can do it? or see here http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2006/01/04/64871.aspx an example titled "How To Read/Write Another App.Config File" about using ExeConfigurationFileMap).
   Or
2. Accept it as a parameter that would be passed from your COM application. Then your COM application should get that connection string from registry or from some kind of ini-file.

Either way you'd have to manually provide acquired connection string to Entity Framework. A quick search shows that there is an EntityConnection constructor that accepts connection string as argument, maybe it will suit you.